# Python - Immutable type example

Tags: python

Can someone please tell me how I can use this piece of code?. I'm not sure what question it is I want to ask, I just want to define the class needed to play with it along with other commands that I can give to the interpreter.

This is really making my headspin, because there is no other supporting code for it and I think it might be a metaclass usage.

Thank you,

```
class RoundFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        return float.__new__(cls, round(val, 2))
```

Comment: If you don't know what the question is, how can we know what/how to answer?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: you corrected OP's code and this may be what OP needed, because indentation matters in Python. I believe you may have answered the question within edit ;)

Comment: Guys, thanks for the response.  I just started learning OOP with wesley chuns book, which is not the greatest for a beginner.    I didn't realize that it had something to do with the builtin type float, but that it referenced another class and passed an instance or something to it.  this oop stuff is super hard.

Comment: @user1027217: It is not __super hard__, be patient :) The `float` from the first line of your code is the class from which your new class inherits (in Python there may be more than one class that you inherit from). In the third line you just call one of the methods from the class you inherit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method called `__new__` is the constructor for the class. Don't confuse it with `__init__` which is the class initialiser; the difference is that `__new__` is called before you have an instance of the object and must create and return the instance whereas `__init__` is called after the object has been created.

Usually when you subclass you just override the initialiser to do your own initialisation, but that often doesn't work if you are subclassing an immutable object as you cannot change the actual value of the object after it has been constructed. In this case the code is changing how the float is constructed so it overrides `float.__new__` and then calls it explicitly with a modified argument.

The whole class is a complete waste of time, if you want to create a rounded float just do this:

```
def rounded_float(f): return round(f, 2)
```

or:

```
from functools import partial
rounded_float = partial(round, ndigits=2)
```

and in either case a call to rounded_float returns the value rounded to 2 digits.
Also remember when you are using this function that `rounded_float(1.0/3.0)` doesn't give you exactly `0.33` it just gives you the nearest floating point representation. If you want the exact value for calculation purposes use the `Decimal` class, but if it is for output then just format the number on output.

Comment: class a:
   def __init__(self, returned):
        self.returned = returned
        print self.returned
class example(a):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        return a.__new__(cls)

Comment: I got that piece of code to work and I think it's similar to the float usage. The thing i'm still confused about is this new instance. if i look under the example directory, I see a new. Does that mean that the example function is a single instance to access my a class? Sorry if you can't read my code example above, i can't figure out how to indent it despite adding four spaces.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing crazy going on here. I'll annoate with comments. Although it should be formatted like this:

```
# Inherit from the built in type 'float', 
# so that this can be used anywhere a float can
class RoundFloat(float):
    # __new__ takes care of actually creating the object
    def __new__(cls, val):
        # Pass it off to the float initializer, but round the value first
        return float.__new__(cls, round(val, 2))
```

It's really just a quick way of implementing a float value that's always rounded to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, indent I see is incorrect. The method (constructor) definition should be indented:

```
class RoundFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        return float.__new__(cls, round(val, 2))
```

Second, to use it you can write something like that:

```
a = RoundFloat(3.1236589)
```

and then if you do:

```
print a
```

you will receive:

> 3.12

which is what should be expected here (means: is correct behaviour).

Is it what you asked for? Let me know.

Comment: What does the __new__ do? the examples i've searched reference metaclass

Comment: @user1027217: Show me these examples. the `__new__` method is a constructor - in case of `float.__new__()` you call a constructor of `float` class. Is it clear enough?

Answer (score 1):

You use it like this:

```
a = RoundFloat(10.256)
```

if you now print a:

```
10.26
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want all your number instances to be rounded floats, then  the defined class **RoundFloat** is OK: the numbers will be displayed as rounded floats and will **BE** rounded floats.
That means that if you do operations involving two such numbers, like + - x /, the results of the operations will not be the rounded values of the results involving the unrounded values.

Maybe it is what you want.

But in case you wish:

1) **to work with numbers that keep their exact value** *while being displayed in a rounded manner* , you must just override `__str__`

2) **the result of an operation involving two such instances to give a number being itself such an instance** , you must also override the operations `__add__` , `__div__` , etc

you must take an other way, like with the class **Floot** defined below.

The following code compares results of addition in the two cases.

```
class Floot(float):
    cut = 4
    def __init__(self,x):
        self = x
    def __str__(self):
        return ('%%.%df' % Floot.cut) % self
    def __add__(self,y):
        return Floot(super(Floot,self).__add__(y))
    def __sub__(self,y):
        return Floot(super(Floot,self).__sub__(y))
    def __div__(self,y):
        return Floot(super(Floot,self).__div__(y))
    def __mul__(self,y):
        return Floot(super(Floot,self).__mul__(y))
    def __pow__(self,y):
        return Floot(super(Floot,self).__pow__(y))


class RoundFloat(float):
    def __new__(cls, val):
        return float.__new__(cls, round(val, 4))


a = 5.1275407
b = 0.7003208


print 'class Floot\n***********'

aa = Floot(a)
print 'a                : ',a
print 'aa = Floot(a)    : ',aa

bb = Floot(b)
print '\nb                : ',b
print 'bb = Floot(b)    : ',bb

c  = a+b
cc = aa + bb
print '\nc  = a + b       : ',c
print 'cc = aa+bb       : ',cc

print '\nround(c ,4)      : ',round(c,4)
print 'round(cc,4)      : ',round(cc,4)

print ('\nc  - round(c ,4) : %.10f' % (c  - round(c ,4)) ).rstrip('0')
print ('cc - round(cc,4) : %.10f' % (cc - round(cc,4)) ).rstrip('0')




print '\n\nclass RoundFloat\n****************'

aa = RoundFloat(a)
print 'a                   : ',a
print 'aa = RoundFloat(a)  : ',aa

bb = RoundFloat(b)
print '\nb                   : ',b
print 'bb = RoundFloat(b)  : ',bb

c  = a+b
cc = aa + bb
print '\nc  = a + b          : ',c
print 'cc = aa+bb          : ',cc

print '\nround(c ,4)         : ',round(c,4)
print 'round(cc,4)         : ',round(cc,4)

print ('\nc  - round(c ,4)    : % .10f' % (c  - round(c ,4)) ).rstrip('0')
print ('cc - round(cc,4)    : % .10f' % (cc - round(cc,4)) ).rstrip('0')
```

The fact that Floot(5.1275407) + Floot(0.7003208) is displayed as 5.8279, despite the fact Floot(5.1275407) is displayed as 5.1275 and Floot(0.7003208) displayed as 0.7003, betrays the fact that the real values of these Floot instances are more precise than their displaying.

The fact that `cc - round(cc,4)` has the same value than `c  - round(c,4)` betrays the same: **Floot(a) + Floot(b)** and **a + b** have in fact the same value, despite how they are displayed